# Better way to debug JS with generators in IntelliJ or WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, generator

I am working on a webapp in Node JS, using the Koa framework.

All the flow control is done with generators, instead of callbacks. The code looks sequential, though the actual flow is not. Anyway it looks much cleaner thant callback hell.

Here is a simple example of a controller function written with koa :

```
function *findUserById(userId)
{
    var user = yield getUserOrError404(userId);
    yield loadAdditionalData(user);
    yield data.users.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

Howeve there is one difficulty : stepping through code with `yield`s in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) does not work very well. Once the execution is on the line with the `yield` statement, if I just "step over", the execution flows goes up the stack to koa code (this is not really the IDE's fault since it just follows the actual flow of execution of the generators, yield statements and Node event loop).

Currently I have to set a breakpoint to the next statement I want the debugger to pause, frequently the next line, and click the "Resume program" button.

It can become tedious when there are more than 2-3 yield statements.

Is there a better way (trick, plugin,...) to step through generator-heavy JS code that allow to step over a yield statement as if it were a "normal" sequential statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the `Run To Cursor` command - this runs effectively like a lightweight breakpoint that is removed after execution reaches the line your cursor is currently on.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benwhite-deltas/0d39866edf001735ae46) for a screenshot of the button you can use for this, and a test harness file I used to check whether this works (it does; at least in PhpStorm, so I'd expect WebStorm to function the same as far as JS is concerned).

Edit : It works perfectly well in IntelliJ too. In addition to the button shown in the screenshot, you can also trigger it by right-clicking on the line and then click "Run to cursor" in the contextual menu. Or the [alt]+[F9] keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That is already a great improvement over the breakpoints method. Thank you ! I wish there was a more avanced "emulation" method of transparently stepping over generator calls though. I'll wait a bit, maybe somebody can come up with such magic... otherwise I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Oh, and useful also for regular debugging sessions ;)

Comment: I'll accept your answer, until, maybe, hopefully, some day, tools like IntelliJ have a "generator aware" debugging mode that allow stepping over yield statements transparently.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more of a "step under" command? ;) In seriousness, we could add a feature request for this at the [Jetbrains Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)